# How to programatically set the instance count for an Azure compute service

Tags: azure, cloud

I read [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/dbbf14d1-fd40-4aa3-8c65-a2424702816b/few-question-regarding-changing-instance-count-programmatically?forum=windowsazuredevelopment&prof=required) that it is possible to programmatically set the instance count of an Azure compute service role using the Rest API method [Change Deployment Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee460809.aspx).

However the docs for that method don't mention role instances, just some cryptic extension properties. Does anyone know how this is done and can perhaps provide some pointers or a code snippet?

It's not the AutoScaling that I'm interested in, but being able to set the exact number of instances in response to custom events.

Comment: Just curious, what kind of events are you looking to trigger your scaling actions on?

Comment: @Igorek there some events, like period time at night and day and others at your own business.

Comment: Little late of a response, but if you're still in need, look into CloudMonix @ http://cloudmonix.com - it has an extensive set of features designed to allow you to run custom actions like this without a need to develop and host your own custom scaling solutions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case you're interested in increasing instance count, then only way to do so is setting the new instance count in service configuration file and then performing `Change Deployment Configuration` operation as you mentioned. Do take a look at Windows Azure PowerShell Cmdlets as it has a Cmdlet called [`Set-AzureRole`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152841.aspx) which will do the job for you.

Similarly if you want to reduce the number of instances, again you can take the same approach. With this approach instances are removed from bottom to top e.g. if you have 4 instances running (X_IN_0, X_IN_1, X_IN_2, and X_IN_3) and you want to remove 2 instances, then always X_IN_3 and X_IN_2 are removed). So if you don't care if last instances are removed, then you can use the same approach.

However there's a new operation available in Windows Azure Service Management API which gives you the power of removing specific instance: `Delete Role Instances`. You can read about that operation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/dn469418.aspx. This is really handy if you wish to take out one particular instance which is behaving erratically. I wrote a blog post about the same which you can read here: http://gauravmantri.com/2013/10/16/a-new-version-of-windows-azure-service-management-api-is-available-with-delete-specific-role-instances-and-more-goodies/.

Comment: That's useful. So what does the Set-AzureRole cmdlet do under the hood? Perhaps it creates a config file and calls the Change Deployment REST API? Is this config file documented anywhere? Thanks.

Comment: My guess is that it reads the config file and then change the `count` attribute value of `<instances>` element and then calls Change Deployment REST API. Please see this link for config file schema: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee758710.aspx.

Comment: The code for all of the PowerShell cmdlets are on GitHub at https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools.  If you ever wonder how it does something the code is all there to dig through. Looks like Guarav is correct, it's just setting the configuration in the config and updating. https://github.com/WindowsAzure/azure-sdk-tools/blob/83648e3c9e8cdcf5ac35f28da3999d5f680f89b4/WindowsAzurePowershell/src/Commands.ServiceManagement/HostedServices/SetAzureRole.cs

Answer (score 2):

There is a Set-AzureRole cmdlet, which lets you specify the number of instances
[Set-AzureRole (MSDN reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn495223.aspx)

Here is an example:

`Set-AzureRole -ServiceName $service -Slot $slot -RoleName "your-role-name" -Count 1`

Comment: Command line is not what he appears to want.  "...using the Rest API"